# Checkbox values are not correctly being saved on AJAX call. (WordPress)

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm creating a Theme Function on WordPress. I want make a specific list of posts on backend and show them on specific part on frontend. I only want to manage/update the same list if I want to change posts on that list.
I created a file 'flash-news-management.php' which I've included to 'functions.php' and I created a 'custom.js' file to handle data and rows. I can select a post and add it to the table as a new row where there are 3 fields 1. Post Title, 2.Show Image and 3.Show Excerpt. Show Image and Show Excerpt is a checkbox field which I update on wp_options table with 'flash_news_list_data' option.
Now where I got stuck is every time I check on the checkbox, the data on the database gets inserted as 0 instead of 1.
I hope somebody will help me out.

These are my codes:

custom.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var counter = 1;

    // Load saved data when the page loads
    var savedData = flash_news_manager.savedData;

    for (var postId in savedData) {
        var postTitle = savedData[postId].postTitle;
        var showImage = savedData[postId].showImage;
        var showExcerpt = savedData[postId].showExcerpt;

        var newRow = '<tr id="row-' + counter + '" data-postid="' + postId + '">';
        newRow += '<td>' + counter + '</td>';
        newRow += '<td>' + postTitle + '</td>';
        newRow += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="showImageCheckbox" name="show_image[]" ' + (showImage == 1 ? 'checked' : '') + '></td>';
        newRow += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="showExcerptCheckbox" name="show_excerpt[]" ' + (showExcerpt == 1 ? 'checked' : '') + '></td>';
        newRow += '<td><button class="remove-button" data-rowid="' + counter + '">Remove</button></td>';
        newRow += '</tr>';

        $('#flash-news-list').append(newRow);

        counter++;
    }

    // When the 'Add to List' button is clicked
    $('#add-to-list').on('click', function () {
        var postId = $('#post-select').val();
        var postTitle = $('#post-select option:selected').text();

        var newRow = '<tr id="row-' + counter + '" data-postid="' + postId + '">';
        newRow += '<td>' + counter + '</td>';
        newRow += '<td>' + postTitle + '</td>';
        
        newRow += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="showImageCheckbox" name="show_image[]" ' + (showImage ? 'checked' : '') + '></td>';
        var showImageCheckbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('.showImageCheckbox');
        // Convert boolean values to integers (1 or 0)
        var showImage = showImageCheckbox.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

        newRow += '<td><input type="checkbox" class="showExcerptCheckbox" name="show_excerpt[]" ' + (showExcerpt ? 'checked' : '') + '></td>';
        var showExcerptCheckbox = $(this).closest('tr').find('.showExcerptCheckbox');        
        // Convert boolean values to integers (1 or 0)
        var showExcerpt = showExcerptCheckbox.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

        newRow += '<td><button class="remove-button" data-rowid="' + counter + '">Remove</button></td>';
        newRow += '</tr>';

        $('#flash-news-list').append(newRow);

        counter++;

        $('#post-select').val('');

        // Save the post data via AJAX
        savePostData(postId, postTitle, showImage, showExcerpt);
    });



    // When a 'Remove' button is clicked
    $('#flash-news-list').on('click', '.remove-button', function () {
        var rowId = $(this).data('rowid');
        var postId = $('#row-' + rowId).data('postid');

        // Remove the row from the list
        $('#row-' + rowId).remove();

        // Remove the post data via AJAX
        removePostData(postId);
    });
    
    // Function to save post data via AJAX
    function savePostData(postId, postTitle, showImage, showExcerpt) {
        var data = {
            action: 'save_post_data',
            post_id: postId,
            post_title: postTitle,
            show_image: showImage,
            show_excerpt: showExcerpt,
        };

        // Ensure the values are integers (0 or 1)
        data.show_image = data.show_image ? 1 : 0;
        data.show_excerpt = data.show_excerpt ? 1 : 0;

        $.post(flash_news_manager.ajax_url, data);
    }

    // Function to remove post data via AJAX
    function removePostData(postId) {
        var data = {
            action: 'remove_post_data',
            post_id: postId,
        };

        $.post(flash_news_manager.ajax_url, data);
    }

    // When the 'Save List' button is clicked
    $('#save-list').on('click', function () {
        console.log('Save List Button Clicked.');
        var postData = [];
        $('#flash-news-list tbody tr').each(function () {
            var postId = $(this).data('postid');

            var showImage = $(this).find('input[name="show_image[]"]').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // Process as integer
            var showExcerpt = $(this).find('input[name="show_excerpt[]"]').is(':checked') ? 1 : 0; // Process as integer
            
            postData.push({
                postId: postId,
                showImage: showImage,
                showExcerpt: showExcerpt,
            });
        });

        // Define and populate the data variable before sending the AJAX request
        var data = {
            action: 'save_list_data',
            list_data: postData || [], // Ensure postData is an array
        };
        
        // Send the AJAX request
        saveListData(data);
    });

    // Function to save list data via AJAX
    function saveListData(data) {
        data.list_data = data.list_data || []; // Ensure that list_data is an array

        console.log('Sending AJAX request to save list data.'); // Add this line for debugging

        $.post(flash_news_manager.ajax_url, data, function (response) {
            if (response.success) {
                console.log("Success");
                $('#save-success-message').show().fadeOut(3000);
            }
        }).fail(function (response) {
            console.log('AJAX request failed:', response.responseText);
        });
    }
});
```

flash-news-management.php:

```
<?php
function add_flash_news_manager_menu_item() {
    add_menu_page(
        'Flash News Manager',
        'Flash News',
        'manage_options',
        'flash-news-manager',
        'flash_news_manager_page_content',
        'dashicons-superhero',
        6
    );
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_flash_news_manager_menu_item');

function enqueue_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}

function enqueue_custom_js() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'flash_news_manager', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ));
}

add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_jquery');
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_js');

function flash_news_manager_page_content() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h2>Flash News Manager</h2>';
    echo '<p>Manage your flash news. Select from the list of recent posts and create a new list.</p>';

    // Load saved data and pass it to JavaScript
    $saved_data = get_option('flash_news_list_data', array());
    wp_localize_script('custom-js', 'flash_news_manager', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'savedData' => $saved_data,
    ));

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );
    $recent_posts = get_posts($args);

    echo '<label for="post-select">Select a Post:</label>';
    echo '<select id="post-select">';
    foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
        echo '<option value="' . $post->ID . '">' . esc_html($post->post_title) . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';

    echo '<button id="add-to-list">Add to List</button>';
    echo '<button id="save-list">Save List</button>';
    echo '<div id="save-success-message" style="display: none; color: green;">List saved successfully.</div>';

    echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th>SN</th>';
    echo '<th>Post Title</th>';
    echo '<th>Show Image</th>';
    echo '<th>Show Excerpt</th>';
    echo '<th>Action</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody id="flash-news-list"></tbody>';
    echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}

function save_post_data() {
    // Sanitize and validate the input
    $post_id = absint($_POST['post_id']);
    $post_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['post_title']);
    $show_image = isset($_POST['show_image[]']) ? 1 : 0;
    $show_excerpt = isset($_POST['show_excerpt[]']) ? 1 : 0;

    // Save post data to the consistent option name
    $list = get_option('flash_news_list_data', array());
    $list[$post_id] = array('postTitle' => $post_title, 'showImage' => $show_image, 'showExcerpt' => $show_excerpt);
    update_option('flash_news_list_data', $list);
    error_log('Received post_id: ' . $post_id);
    error_log('Received post_title: ' . $post_title);
    error_log('Received show_image: ' . $show_image);
    error_log('Received show_excerpt: ' . $show_excerpt);
    wp_die();
}

function remove_post_data() {
    $post_id = $_POST['post_id'];

    // Remove post data from the consistent option name
    $list = get_option('flash_news_list_data', array());
    if (isset($list[$post_id])) {
        unset($list[$post_id]);
        update_option('flash_news_list_data', $list);
    }

    wp_die();
}


function save_list_data() {
    $list_data = $_POST['list_data'];

    // Ensure that $list_data is an array (it should be an array of post data)
    if (is_array($list_data)) {
        // Sanitize and validate the data within the array
        foreach ($list_data as &$post_data) {
            $post_data['postId'] = absint($post_data['postId']);
            $post_data['showImage'] = isset($post_data['showImage']) ? 1 : 0; // Process as integer
            $post_data['showExcerpt'] = isset($post_data['showExcerpt']) ? 1 : 0; // Process as integer
        }

        // Save the list data to a WordPress option
        update_option('flash_news_list_data', $list_data);

        // Send a success response
        wp_send_json_success('List saved successfully.');
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the received data is not in the expected format
        wp_send_json_error('Invalid data format.');
    }
}

add_action('wp_ajax_save_post_data', 'save_post_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_post_data', 'save_post_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_remove_post_data', 'remove_post_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_post_data', 'remove_post_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_save_list_data', 'save_list_data');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_save_list_data', 'save_list_data');
```

I created a file 'flash-news-management.php' which I've included to 'functions.php' and I created a 'custom.js' file to handle data and rows. I can select a post and add it to the table as a new row where there are 3 fields 1. Post Title, 2.Show Image and 3.Show Excerpt. Show Image and Show Excerpt is a checkbox field which I update on wp_options table with 'flash_news_list_data' option.
Now where I got stuck is every time I check on the checkbox, the data on the database gets inserted as 0 instead of 1.